# if cell in openpyxl (ws) contains a certain section of string return as output

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am stuck on something relatively easy and cant seem to figure it out..

I have an input where I enter half a partial name of the string I want to find

```
        # Look for IDC S/N column
        counter = 0
        for col in df.columns:
            if col == 'IDC S/N':
                break
            else:
                counter += 1
        idc_column = counter

        # Will allow conversion of letters to number(s)
        characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

        # Converted numbers to letters - 1 = A , 2 = B
        header = characters[idc_column]
       
        counter = 0 
        for x in ws[header]:
            if x.str.lower().str.contains(num.lower()):
                logger.info(x)
            else:
                print(x)
```

Output :

```
    if x.str.lower().str.contains(num.lower()):
AttributeError: 'Cell' object has no attribute 'str'
```

for example if num input is 70 I would want it to go over all IDC S/N column and print everything that contains this

So the output for 70 should be - [image]

This is a perfect example of what I want to achieve but in pandas

```
df = df.loc[df['IDC S/N'].str.lower().str.contains(num.lower(), na=False)]
```

Comment: Looks like you're confusing openpyxl worksheets with Pandas dataframes.

Comment: @CharlieClark Thanks Charlie, fixed it.. I already solved the issue though :)

Comment: You fixed it by ignoring your typo? Well done.

Comment: i think you're confused buddy. I am just using dataframes to get certain things on my openpyxl done.. but the rest of the script has to be written in openyxl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using just `openpyxl`:

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(r'spreadsheet.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

num = '70'

# Look for IDC S/N column
for cell in ws[1]:
    if cell.value == 'IDC S/N':
        idc_column = cell.column_letter
        break

# Iterate over each cell in the IDC S/N column
for cell in ws[idc_column]:
    value = cell.value
    
    # Make sure the value is a string before using the "in" operator.
    # It could be int, float, NoneType, datetime
    if isinstance(value, str):
        if num in value:
            print(f'{num} found in cell {cell.coordinate}: {value}')
```

Output with my little test spreadsheet:
`70 found in cell B5: S508G070U`

You can get the column letter from the `column_letter` attribute of the `cell`, so you don't need to manually convert the index to a letter. It's also worth noting `openpyxl` has a function `get_column_letter` that converts a column index into a column letter, in case you only had an index.